# SQL Database automatic back up

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have an SQL database - I need to back it up everyday (at a minimum) - preferably multiple times a day - automatically so it definitely gets done.

I'm running Windows which the SQL database is stored on

What programs (prefer free ones) can I use to back it up - I'm completely new with SQL so if you're gonna explain something - do it in layman's terms thanks (:

It needs to get backed up to another server (on the lan).

Cheers for any help you can give!

Comment: Hi Chuck,

It sounds like you are using MS SQL Server since you specified windows.  Is it the express edition?  I used to see this question a lot so I created a video tutorial on how to do it through the GUI.  It's rather in depth and goes through a lot of different facets, if you want something quicker check out:
SQL Backup And Restore For The Accidental DBA


  [1]: http://alirazeghi.com/sysadmindba/
  [2]: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-backup-and-restore-for-the-accidental-dba/

Comment: Good point by Ali. My answer assumes SQL Server and a non-Express edition.

Comment: Hello, I'm not too sure what it is - I don't believe its express edition because it doesn't say it anywhere.  I've had a look at the links you provided - however can you also provide your video link?

Comment: I found the video and tried it out - however when I try and backup to the server I get an "operating system error 5 reason 15105" - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this directly through SQL Server. You can schedule the backups through SQL Server Agent and just call the backup command through the job. The job will allow you to schedule it as you please.

To make this even a bit easier you can create a Maintenance Plan directly in SQL Server and specify backing up the database.

There are a few options here, and no need to look outside of SQL Server for this functionality.

Here's an article on how to do this through a maintenance plan: http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2010/01/20/scheduling-automated-backup-using-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: Hi Thomas - thanks for your answer! however I can't find SQL server agent in my list - is there somewhere I need to turn it on from?

Comment: What does select @@version return?

Comment: I thankyou for your help however I found a different way - I used "SQLBACKUPANDFTP" does all that I need (: Thanks for your help both of you!